# ElasticSearch Aggregate by attribute in field which is list

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have some articles, each article may have some reviewers and each reviewer may have different approve status like following:

```
{
  ArticleId: 1,
  Title: "1",
  Reviewers: [
    {
       "Reviewer": "abc",
       "Status": "Pending"
    },
    {
       "Reviewer": "def",
       "Status": "Approved"
    }
  ]
}

{
  ArticleId: 2,
  Title: "2",
  Reviewers: [
    {
       "Reviewer": "abc",
       "Status": "Approved"
    },
    {
       "Reviewer": "def",
       "Status": "Approved"
    }
  ]
}

{
  ArticleId: 3,
  Title: "2",
  Reviewers: [
    {
       "Reviewer": "def",
       "Status": "Approved"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to saves this data in the ES and search all articles having abc as reviewer, and aggregate by abc's review status.

```
{
 ...
 buckets:[{
        "doc_count": "1",
        "Key": "Pending"
    },{
        "doc_count": "1",
        "Key": "Approved"
    }]
}
```

I was wondering how to do it in ES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption:** Reviewers is a nested type.

Try below query. Details as comment in the code.

```
 {
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {              // <========== Use nested aggregation
        "path": "Reviewers"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Reviewers.Reviewer.keyword": "abc" // <========= Filter docs with reviewer = abc
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "Reviewers.Status.keyword", // <======= aggregate based on reviewer status
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```